# Printing the equation of the best fit line

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have created the best fit lines for the dataset using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for dd,KK in DATASET.groupby('Z'):
  fit = polyfit(x,y,3)
  fit_fn = poly1d(fit)
  ax.plot(KK['x'],KK['y'],'o',KK['x'], fit_fn(KK['x']),'k',linewidth=4)
  ax.set_xlabel('x')
  ax.set_ylabel('y')
```

The graph displays the best fit line for each group of Z. I want print the equation of the best fit line on top of the line.Please suggest what can i do out here [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you need to write some function that convert a poly parameters array to a latex string, here is an example:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(100)
y = 1 + 2 * x + 3 * x * x + np.random.randn(100) * 2

poly = pl.polyfit(x, y, 2)

def poly2latex(poly, variable="x", width=2):
    t = ["{0:0.{width}f}"]
    t.append(t[-1] + " {variable}")
    t.append(t[-1] + "^{1}")

    def f():
        for i, v in enumerate(reversed(poly)):
            idx = i if i < 2 else 2
            yield t[idx].format(v, i, variable=variable, width=width)

    return "${}$".format("+".join(f()))

pl.plot(x, y, "o", alpha=0.4)
x2 = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
y2 = np.polyval(poly, x2)
pl.plot(x2, y2, lw=2, color="r")
pl.text(x2[5], y2[5], poly2latex(poly), fontsize=16)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner.

If `fit` is the `poly1d` object, while plotting the fitted line, just use `label` argument as bellow,

`label='y=${}$'.format(''.join(['{}x^{}'.format(('{:.2f}'.format(j) if j<0 else '+{:.2f}'.format(j)),(len(fit.coef)-i-1)) for i,j in enumerate(fit.coef)]))`

Comment: Doesn't look like this would go well with the lines on the example plot, as those are completely black and thus wouldn't be discernible on the legend. Also, forcing this into one line really hurts readability. But yeah, it's a solution nonetheless!

Comment: The point on readability just got reinforced with the latest edit.